# linking to another php page and include header and footer

Tags: php, header, footer

I am a beginner,  just trying to learn php. Below is my index.php file:

```
<?php
  include("header.php");
  require_once('connect.php');
  include("home.php");
  include("footer.php");
?>
```

I made a simple test site that has the home page included inside the index.php file. Do I have to use `include(header.php);` on every page if I want to include the same code?
Thanks.

Comment: So if you don't include header on another page - how it will be included?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: The way you are currently doing it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have include header.php on every page.
Try this:

```
<?php include("header.php");?>
<div class="container">
   <?php include ("home.php");?>
</div>
<?php include ("footer.php");?>
```

Keep the header and footer, just change the contents( home.php, otherpage.php, ... ).
I recommend you to use jQuery to dynamically load the content of `container`